# Querying Google Images

Tags: querying, google-image-search

I am currently writing a program that needs to be able to query Google Images with a certain keyword and download, for example, the first 300 results. After researching, I learned that the Google Images API has been deprecated so I am not really sure what to do. Any suggestions as to how one would go about this would be very helpful.

Comment: I wrote a program to do this, it uses bash and phantomjs (captive browser).  It's not ideal, but it does work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524218/download-first-1000-images-from-google-search

Comment: i wrote a script using python that can use google search and download highresolution images from google http://stackoverflow.com/a/28487500/2875380

Comment: https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download

Answer (score 0):

There is ajax google function for that. You can search images by query. https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide

There are some examples code for using with Flash, using with Java, using with PHP, using with Python and using with Perl.