# Python - Download Images from google Image search?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to download all Images of google image search using python . The code I am using seems to have some problem some times .My code is

```
import os
import sys
import time
from urllib import FancyURLopener
import urllib2
import simplejson

# Define search term
searchTerm = "parrot"

# Replace spaces ' ' in search term for '%20' in order to comply with request
searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(' ','%20')


# Start FancyURLopener with defined version 
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener): 
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127     Firefox/2.0.0.11'
    myopener = MyOpener()

    # Set count to 0
    count= 0

    for i in range(0,10):
    # Notice that the start changes for each iteration in order to request a new set of   images for each loop
    url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?' + 'v=1.0& q='+searchTerm+'&start='+str(i*10)+'&userip=MyIP')
    print url
    request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'Referer': 'testing'})
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

# Get results using JSON
    results = simplejson.load(response)
    data = results['responseData']
    dataInfo = data['results']

# Iterate for each result and get unescaped url
    for myUrl in dataInfo:
        count = count + 1
        my_url = myUrl['unescapedUrl']
        myopener.retrieve(myUrl['unescapedUrl'],str(count)+'.jpg')
```

After downloading few pages I am getting an error as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Python27\img_google3.py", line 37, in <module>
    dataInfo = data['results']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What to do ??????

Comment: A) Post your code, B) use Google's image search API to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22871658/538284

Comment: https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download

Answer (score 53):

I have modified my code. Now the code can download 100 images for a given query, and images are full high resolution that is original images are being downloaded.

I am downloading the images using urllib2 & Beautiful soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import urllib2
import os
import cookielib
import json

def get_soup(url,header):
    return BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url,headers=header)),'html.parser')


query = raw_input("query image")# you can change the query for the image  here
image_type="ActiOn"
query= query.split()
query='+'.join(query)
url="https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+query+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
print url
#add the directory for your image here
DIR="Pictures"
header={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"
}
soup = get_soup(url,header)


ActualImages=[]# contains the link for Large original images, type of  image
for a in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"rg_meta"}):
    link , Type =json.loads(a.text)["ou"]  ,json.loads(a.text)["ity"]
    ActualImages.append((link,Type))

print  "there are total" , len(ActualImages),"images"

if not os.path.exists(DIR):
            os.mkdir(DIR)
DIR = os.path.join(DIR, query.split()[0])

if not os.path.exists(DIR):
            os.mkdir(DIR)
###print images
for i , (img , Type) in enumerate( ActualImages):
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(img, headers={'User-Agent' : header})
        raw_img = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

        cntr = len([i for i in os.listdir(DIR) if image_type in i]) + 1
        print cntr
        if len(Type)==0:
            f = open(os.path.join(DIR , image_type + "_"+ str(cntr)+".jpg"), 'wb')
        else :
            f = open(os.path.join(DIR , image_type + "_"+ str(cntr)+"."+Type), 'wb')


        f.write(raw_img)
        f.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print "could not load : "+img
        print e
```

i hope this helps you

Comment: @rishabhr0y How are you specifying how many images to retrieve? What if we want to get more than 100?

Comment: @mxdg  sorry cant retrieve more than 100 images  using this method

Comment: Possible to specify the number to images? I only want top 5 images for each query

Comment: yes it is possible @d2a2d  just replace this line                                           
    for i , (img , Type) in enumerate( ActualImages): to                                                                                                          for i , (img , Type) in enumerate( ActualImages[:5]):                                                                      u just need to iterate over 5 elments on the actual images list

Comment: What exactly is this piece doing  `link , Type =json.loads(a.text)["ou"]  ,json.loads(a.text)["ity"]`? I'm running into an error when trying to run it from jupyter notebook `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Is it still working? It returned 0 images for my query.

Comment: @PallavBakshi the code is still working fine for me could u  post  the error or the logs you get when you run the code ??

Comment: Hey @rishabhr0y I solved it back then. Thank you for your reply. I think it worked. I have already upvoted the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: absolutely fine.

Comment: This is no longer working (for me). I think a headless browser with JavaScript is now required. I made a new script google-images.py in Python using Selenium and Chrome headless: http://sam.aiki.info/b/google-images.py

Answer (score 26):

The [Google Image Search API is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/image-search/), you need to use the [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) for what you want to achieve. To fetch the images you need to do this:

```
import urllib2
import simplejson
import cStringIO

fetcher = urllib2.build_opener()
searchTerm = 'parrot'
startIndex = 0
searchUrl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=" + searchTerm + "&start=" + startIndex
f = fetcher.open(searchUrl)
deserialized_output = simplejson.load(f)
```

This will give you 4 results, as JSON, you need to iteratively get the results by incrementing the `startIndex` in the API request.

To get the images you need to use a library like [cStringIO](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-cStringIO.html).

For example, to access the first image, you need to do this:

```
imageUrl = deserialized_output['responseData']['results'][0]['unescapedUrl']
file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(imageUrl).read())
img = Image.open(file)
```

Comment: You want to use http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images instead of http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web

Comment: Yep, that's what ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images  will give you. ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web  will just give you webpage search results.

Comment: @SebaK: My bad, I misread your comment. Corrected. Thanks. :)

Comment: nice :) via google api  in case any one need web search api url is : http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=search term

Comment: For what it's worth, the ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images address now returns 403: This API is no longer available.

Comment: I get the same problem: print deserialized_output
{'responseData': None, 'responseDetails': 'This API is no longer available.', 'responseStatus': 403}

Comment: This API is now no longer available.

Answer (score 18):

Google deprecated their API, scraping Google is complicated, so I would suggest using Bing API instead to automatically download images. The pip package [bing-image-downloader](https://pypi.org/project/bing-image-downloader/) allows you to easily download an arbitrary number of images to a directory with a single line of code.

```
from bing_image_downloader import downloader

downloader.download(query_string, limit=100, output_dir='dataset', adult_filter_off=True, force_replace=False, timeout=60, verbose=True)
```

Google is not so good, and Microsoft is not so evil

Comment: Even Bing API seems to have been deprecated.
The page shows following message:
"DataMarket and Data Services are being retired and will stop accepting new orders after 12/31/2016. Existing subscriptions will be retired and cancelled starting 3/31/2017. Please reach out to your service provider for options if you want to continue service."

Comment: This worked well as of May 2022 (`python 3.8` and `bing-image-downloader==1.1.2`)

Answer (score 7):

Here's my latest google image snarfer, written in Python, using Selenium and headless Chrome.

It requires `python-selenium`, the `chromium-driver`, and a module called `retry` from pip.

Link: http://sam.aiki.info/b/google-images.py

Example Usage:

```
google-images.py tiger 10 --opts isz:lt,islt:svga,itp:photo > urls.txt
parallel=5
user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"
(i=0; while read url; do wget -e robots=off -T10 --tries 10 -U"$user_agent" "$url" -O`printf %04d $i`.jpg & i=$(($i+1)) ; [ $(($i % $parallel)) = 0 ] && wait; done < urls.txt; wait)
```

Help Usage:

```
$ google-images.py --help
usage: google-images.py [-h] [--safe SAFE] [--opts OPTS] query n

Fetch image URLs from Google Image Search.

positional arguments:
  query        image search query
  n            number of images (approx)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --safe SAFE  safe search [off|active|images]
  --opts OPTS  search options, e.g.
               isz:lt,islt:svga,itp:photo,ic:color,ift:jpg
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# requires: selenium, chromium-driver, retry

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import selenium.common.exceptions as sel_ex
import sys
import time
import urllib.parse
from retry import retry
import argparse
import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()
retry_logger = None

css_thumbnail = "img.Q4LuWd"
css_large = "img.n3VNCb"
css_load_more = ".mye4qd"
selenium_exceptions = (sel_ex.ElementClickInterceptedException, sel_ex.ElementNotInteractableException, sel_ex.StaleElementReferenceException)

def scroll_to_end(wd):
    wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

@retry(exceptions=KeyError, tries=6, delay=0.1, backoff=2, logger=retry_logger)
def get_thumbnails(wd, want_more_than=0):
    wd.execute_script("document.querySelector('{}').click();".format(css_load_more))
    thumbnails = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(css_thumbnail)
    n_results = len(thumbnails)
    if n_results <= want_more_than:
        raise KeyError("no new thumbnails")
    return thumbnails

@retry(exceptions=KeyError, tries=6, delay=0.1, backoff=2, logger=retry_logger)
def get_image_src(wd):
    actual_images = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(css_large)
    sources = []
    for img in actual_images:
        src = img.get_attribute("src")
        if src.startswith("http") and not src.startswith("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/"):
            sources.append(src)
    if not len(sources):
        raise KeyError("no large image")
    return sources

@retry(exceptions=selenium_exceptions, tries=6, delay=0.1, backoff=2, logger=retry_logger)
def retry_click(el):
    el.click()

def get_images(wd, start=0, n=20, out=None):
    thumbnails = []
    count = len(thumbnails)
    while count < n:
        scroll_to_end(wd)
        try:
            thumbnails = get_thumbnails(wd, want_more_than=count)
        except KeyError as e:
            logger.warning("cannot load enough thumbnails")
            break
        count = len(thumbnails)
    sources = []
    for tn in thumbnails:
        try:
            retry_click(tn)
        except selenium_exceptions as e:
            logger.warning("main image click failed")
            continue
        sources1 = []
        try:
            sources1 = get_image_src(wd)
        except KeyError as e:
            pass
            # logger.warning("main image not found")
        if not sources1:
            tn_src = tn.get_attribute("src")
            if not tn_src.startswith("data"):
                logger.warning("no src found for main image, using thumbnail")          
                sources1 = [tn_src]
            else:
                logger.warning("no src found for main image, thumbnail is a data URL")
        for src in sources1:
            if not src in sources:
                sources.append(src)
                if out:
                    print(src, file=out)
                    out.flush()
        if len(sources) >= n:
            break
    return sources

def google_image_search(wd, query, safe="off", n=20, opts='', out=None):
    search_url_t = "https://www.google.com/search?safe={safe}&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&q={q}&oq={q}&gs_l=img&tbs={opts}"
    search_url = search_url_t.format(q=urllib.parse.quote(query), opts=urllib.parse.quote(opts), safe=safe)
    wd.get(search_url)
    sources = get_images(wd, n=n, out=out)
    return sources

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Fetch image URLs from Google Image Search.')
    parser.add_argument('--safe', type=str, default="off", help='safe search [off|active|images]')
    parser.add_argument('--opts', type=str, default="", help='search options, e.g. isz:lt,islt:svga,itp:photo,ic:color,ift:jpg')
    parser.add_argument('query', type=str, help='image search query')
    parser.add_argument('n', type=int, default=20, help='number of images (approx)')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    opts = Options()
    opts.add_argument("--headless")
    # opts.add_argument("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false")
    with webdriver.Chrome(options=opts) as wd:
        sources = google_image_search(wd, args.query, safe=args.safe, n=args.n, opts=args.opts, out=sys.stdout)

main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Haven't looked into your code but this is an example solution made with selenium to try to get 400 pictures from the search term

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import json
import os
import urllib2

searchterm = 'vannmelon' # will also be the name of the folder
url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+searchterm+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
header={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"}
counter = 0
succounter = 0

if not os.path.exists(searchterm):
    os.mkdir(searchterm)

for _ in range(500):
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,10000)")

for x in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='rg_meta']"):
    counter = counter + 1
    print "Total Count:", counter
    print "Succsessful Count:", succounter
    print "URL:",json.loads(x.get_attribute('innerHTML'))["ou"]

    img = json.loads(x.get_attribute('innerHTML'))["ou"]
    imgtype = json.loads(x.get_attribute('innerHTML'))["ity"]
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(img, headers={'User-Agent': header})
        raw_img = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
        File = open(os.path.join(searchterm , searchterm + "_" + str(counter) + "." + imgtype), "wb")
        File.write(raw_img)
        File.close()
        succounter = succounter + 1
    except:
            print "can't get img"

print succounter, "pictures succesfully downloaded"
browser.close()
```

Comment: it's saying 0 picture downloaded. google close this class ?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to [Piees's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39734952/1799640), for downloading any number of images from the search results, we need to simulate a click on 'Show more results' button after first 400 results are loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import json
import urllib2
import sys
import time

# adding path to geckodriver to the OS environment variable
# assuming that it is stored at the same path as this script
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.getcwd()
download_path = "dataset/"

def main():
    searchtext = sys.argv[1] # the search query
    num_requested = int(sys.argv[2]) # number of images to download
    number_of_scrolls = num_requested / 400 + 1 
    # number_of_scrolls * 400 images will be opened in the browser

    if not os.path.exists(download_path + searchtext.replace(" ", "_")):
        os.makedirs(download_path + searchtext.replace(" ", "_"))

    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+searchtext+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)

    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
    extensions = {"jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"}
    img_count = 0
    downloaded_img_count = 0

    for _ in xrange(number_of_scrolls):
        for __ in xrange(10):
            # multiple scrolls needed to show all 400 images
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000000)")
            time.sleep(0.2)
        # to load next 400 images
        time.sleep(0.5)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Show more results']").click()
        except Exception as e:
            print "Less images found:", e
            break

    # imges = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="rg_meta"]') # not working anymore
    imges = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"rg_meta")]')
    print "Total images:", len(imges), "\n"
    for img in imges:
        img_count += 1
        img_url = json.loads(img.get_attribute('innerHTML'))["ou"]
        img_type = json.loads(img.get_attribute('innerHTML'))["ity"]
        print "Downloading image", img_count, ": ", img_url
        try:
            if img_type not in extensions:
                img_type = "jpg"
            req = urllib2.Request(img_url, headers=headers)
            raw_img = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
            f = open(download_path+searchtext.replace(" ", "_")+"/"+str(downloaded_img_count)+"."+img_type, "wb")
            f.write(raw_img)
            f.close
            downloaded_img_count += 1
        except Exception as e:
            print "Download failed:", e
        finally:
            print
        if downloaded_img_count >= num_requested:
            break

    print "Total downloaded: ", downloaded_img_count, "/", img_count
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/atif93/google_image_downloader).

Comment: this code was working 1 week ago but now it doesn't find image. Could you modify it ?

Comment: Can you please tell the error/problem you're getting?

Comment: @atif93 your code works but with an exception that less image found ... what it is saying so ?

Comment: Sometimes the Google image results for a query might be less than the <number_of_images> you might have queried for. In that case it says that lesser images were found.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in Windows 10, Python 3.9.7:

> **pip install bing-image-downloader**

Below code downloads *10 images of India* from Bing search Engine to desired output folder:

```
from bing_image_downloader import downloader
downloader.download('India', limit=10,  output_dir='dataset', adult_filter_off=True, force_replace=False, timeout=60, verbose=True)
```

Documentation: https://pypi.org/project/bing-image-downloader/

Comment: this code is still working in 2023, love it

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Selenium with Python. Here is how:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import urllib.request

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
word="apple"
url="http://images.google.com/search?q="+word+"&tbm=isch&sout=1"
driver.get(url)
imageXpathSelector='/html/body/div[2]/c-wiz/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/img'
img=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,imageXpathSelector)

src=(img.get_attribute('src'))
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, word+".jpg")
driver.close()
```

(This code works on Python 3.8)
Please be informed that you should install the Selenium package with '**pip install selenium**'

Contrary to the other web scraping techniques, Selenium opens the browser and downloads the items because Selenium's mission is testing rather than scraping.

N.B. For `imageXpathSelector` if it does not work please click F12 while your browser is open and right-click the image then click the 'copy' menu from the opened menu and select 'copy Xpath' there. It will be the right Xpath location of the element you need.

Answer (score 2):

This one as other code snippets have grown old and no longer worked for me. Downloads 100 images for each keyword, inspired from one of the solutions above.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import os


class GoogleeImageDownloader(object):
    _URL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q={}&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
    _BASE_DIR = 'GoogleImages'
    _HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"
    }

    def __init__(self):
        query = raw_input("Enter keyword to search images\n")
        self.dir_name = os.path.join(self._BASE_DIR, query.split()[0])
        self.url = self._URL.format(urllib2.quote(query)) 
        self.make_dir_for_downloads()
        self.initiate_downloads()

    def make_dir_for_downloads(self):
        print "Creating necessary directories"
        if not os.path.exists(self._BASE_DIR):
            os.mkdir(self._BASE_DIR)

        if not os.path.exists(self.dir_name):
            os.mkdir(self.dir_name)

    def initiate_downloads(self):
        src_list = []
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(self.url,headers=self._HEADERS)),'html.parser')
        for img in soup.find_all('img'):
            if img.has_attr("data-src"):
                src_list.append(img['data-src'])
        print "{} of images collected for downloads".format(len(src_list))
        self.save_images(src_list)

    def save_images(self, src_list):
        print "Saving Images..."
        for i , src in enumerate(src_list):
            try:
                req = urllib2.Request(src, headers=self._HEADERS)
                raw_img = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
                with open(os.path.join(self.dir_name , str(i)+".jpg"), 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(raw_img)
            except Exception as e:
                print ("could not save image")
                raise e


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GoogleeImageDownloader()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I ran across it recently and none of the previous answers work anymore. So I wrote this script to gather images from google. As of right now it can download as many images as are available.

here is a github link to it as well https://github.com/CumminUp07/imengine/blob/master/get_google_images.py

DISCLAIMER: DUE TO COPYRIGHT ISSUES, IMAGES GATHERED SHOULD ONLY BE USED FOR RESEARCH AND EDUCATION PURPOSES ONLY

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import urllib2
import json
import urllib

#programtically go through google image ajax json return and save links to list#
#num_images is more of a suggestion                                            #  
#it will get the ceiling of the nearest 100 if available                       #
def get_links(query_string, num_images):
    #initialize place for links
    links = []
    #step by 100 because each return gives up to 100 links
    for i in range(0,num_images,100):
        url = 'https://www.google.com/search?ei=1m7NWePfFYaGmQG51q7IBg&hl=en&q='+query_string+'\
        &tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjjovnD7sjWAhUGQyYKHTmrC2kQuT0I7gEoAQ&start='+str(i)+'\
        &yv=2&vet=10ahUKEwjjovnD7sjWAhUGQyYKHTmrC2kQuT0I7gEoAQ.1m7NWePfFYaGmQG51q7IBg.i&ijn=1&asearch=ichunk&async=_id:rg_s,_pms:s'

        #set user agent to avoid 403 error
        request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 

        #returns json formatted string of the html
        json_string = urllib2.urlopen(request).read() 

        #parse as json
        page = json.loads(json_string) 

        #html found here
        html = page[1][1] 

        #use BeautifulSoup to parse as html
        new_soup = Soup(html,'lxml')

        #all img tags, only returns results of search
        imgs = new_soup.find_all('img')

        #loop through images and put src in links list
        for j in range(len(imgs)):
            links.append(imgs[j]["src"])

    return links

#download images                              #
#takes list of links, directory to save to    # 
#and prefix for file names                    #
#saves images in directory as a one up number #
#with prefix added                            #
#all images will be .jpg                      #
def get_images(links,directory,pre):
    for i in range(len(links)):
        urllib.urlretrieve(links[i], "./"+directory+"/"+str(pre)+str(i)+".jpg")

#main function to search images                 #
#takes two lists, base term and secondary terms #
#also takes number of images to download per    #
#combination                                    #
#it runs every combination of search terms      #
#with base term first then secondary            #
def search_images(base,terms,num_images):
    for y in range(len(base)):
        for x in range(len(terms)):
            all_links = get_links(base[y]+'+'+terms[x],num_images)
            get_images(all_links,"images",x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    terms = ["cars","numbers","scenery","people","dogs","cats","animals"]
    base = ["animated"]
    search_images(base,terms,1000)
```

Comment: did not work for me - urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: did not work for me, either: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: The link is no longer exist.

Comment: @JaranaManotumruksa which link?

Answer (score 1):

The one I used is :

https://github.com/hellock/icrawler

This package is a mini framework of web crawlers. With modularization design, it is easy to use and extend. It supports media data like images and videos very well, and can also be applied to texts and another type of files. Scrapy is heavy and powerful, while icrawler is tiny and flexible.

```
def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Test built-in crawlers')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--crawler',
        nargs='+',
        default=['google', 'bing', 'baidu', 'flickr', 'greedy', 'urllist'],
        help='which crawlers to test')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    for crawler in args.crawler:
        eval('test_{}()'.format(crawler))
        print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of google image search, try other image searches like `ecosia` or `bing`.

Here is a sample code for retrieving images from `ecosia` search engine.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
headers = {'User-Agent':user_agent} 
urls = ["https://www.ecosia.org/images?q=india%20pan%20card%20example"]
#The url's from which the image is to be extracted.
index = 0

for url in urls:
    request = urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers) #The assembled request
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    data = response.read() # Read the html result page

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    
    for link in soup.find_all('img'):   
        #The images are enclosed in 'img' tag and the 'src' contains the url of the image.
        img_url = link.get('src')
        dest = str(index) + ".jpg"  #Destination to store the image.
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url)
            index += 1
        except:
            continue
```

The code works with google image search but it fails to retrieve images because google stores the images in encrypted format which is difficult to retrieve from the image url.

The solutions works as on 1-Feb-2021.

Comment: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable (June 28,2022)

Answer (score 0):

- You can achieve this using `selenium` as others mentioned it above.
- Alternatively, you can try using [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=lasagna&ijn=0&tbm=isch).

Code and [example](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Download-Google-Images-pythonbs4req). Fuction to download images was taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217788/1291371):

```
import os, time, shutil, httpx, asyncio
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217788/1291371
async def download_file(url):
    print(f'Downloading {url}')

    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/18727481/1291371
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    local_filename = os.path.basename(parsed_url.path)

    os.makedirs('images', exist_ok=True)

    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        async with client.stream('GET', url) as response:
            async with open(f'images/{local_filename}', 'wb') as f:
                await asyncio.to_thread(shutil.copyfileobj, response.raw, f)

    return local_filename

async def main():
    start = time.perf_counter()

    params = {
        "engine": "google",
        "ijn": "0",
        "q": "lasagna",
        "tbm": "isch",
        "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    download_files_tasks = [
        download_file(image['original']) for image in results['images_results']
    ]

    await asyncio.gather(*download_files_tasks, return_exceptions=True)

    print(
        f"Downloaded {len(download_files_tasks)} images in {time.perf_counter() - start:0.4f} seconds")

asyncio.run(main())
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so instead of coding this from you I am going to tell you what you're doing wrong and it might lead you in the right direction. Usually most modern websites render html dynamically via javascript and so if you simply send a GET request(with urllib/CURL/fetch/axios) you wont get what you usually see in the browser going to the same URL/web address. What you need is something that renders the javascript code to create the same HTML/webpage you see on your browser, you can use something like selenium gecko driver for firefox to do this and there python modules out there that let you do this.

I hope this helps, if you still feel lost here's a simple script i wrote a while back to extract something similar from your google photos

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
url="https://photos.app.goo.gl/xxxxxxx"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
regPrms="^background-image\:url\(.*\)$"
regPrms="^The.*Spain$"
html = driver.page_source

urls=re.findall("(?P<url>https?://[^\s\"$]+)", html)

fin=[]
for url in urls:
        if "video-downloads" in url:
            fin.append(url)
print("The Following ZIP contains all your pictures")
for url in fin:
        print("-------------------")
        print(url)
```