# download images from google with command line

Tags: linux, shell, web

I would like to download n-th image that google gives me with command line i.e. like with command `wget`

To search image of `[something]` I just go to page `https://www.google.cz/search?q=[something]&tbm=isch` but how do I get url of n-th search result so I can use wget?

Comment: Why did this question get closed? I do not understand the explanation I got: "We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow" How does that apply, especially when this question happily lived here for 6 years.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**First attempt**

First you need to set the user agent so google will authorize output from searches. Then we can look for images and select the desired one. To accomplish that we insert missing newlines, wget will return google searches on one single line, and filter the link. The index of the file is stored in the variable `count`.

```
$ count=10
$ imagelink=$(wget --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0' -qO - "www.google.be/search?q=something\&tbm=isch" | sed 's/</\n</g' | grep '<img' | head -n"$count" | tail -n1 | sed 's/.*src="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/')
$ wget $imagelink
```

The image will now be in your working directory, you can tweak the last command and specify a desired output file name.

You can summarize it in a shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash
count=${1}
shift
query="$@"
[ -z $query ] && exit 1  # insufficient arguments
imagelink=$(wget --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0' -qO - | "www.google.be/search?q=${query}\&tbm=isch" | sed 's/</\n</g' | grep '<img' | head -n"$count" | tail -n1 | sed 's/.*src="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/')
wget -qO google_image $imagelink
```

Example usage:

```
$ ls
Documents
Downloads
Music
script.sh
$ chmod +x script.sh
$ bash script.sh 5 awesome
$ ls
Documents
Downloads
google_image
Music
script.sh
```

Now the `google_image` should contain the fifth google image when looking for 'awesome'. If you experience any bugs, let me know, I'll take care of them.

**Better code**

The problem with this code is that it returns pictures in low resolution. A better solution is as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

# function to create all dirs til file can be made
function mkdirs {
    file="$1"
    dir="/"

    # convert to full path
    if [ "${file##/*}" ]; then
        file="${PWD}/${file}"
    fi

    # dir name of following dir
    next="${file#/}"

    # while not filename
    while [ "${next//[^\/]/}" ]; do
        # create dir if doesn't exist
        [ -d "${dir}" ] || mkdir "${dir}"
        dir="${dir}/${next%%/*}"
        next="${next#*/}"
    done

    # last directory to make
    [ -d "${dir}" ] || mkdir "${dir}"
}

# get optional 'o' flag, this will open the image after download
getopts 'o' option
[[ $option = 'o' ]] && shift

# parse arguments
count=${1}
shift
query="$@"
[ -z "$query" ] && exit 1  # insufficient arguments

# set user agent, customize this by visiting http://whatsmyuseragent.com/
useragent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'

# construct google link
link="www.google.cz/search?q=${query}\&tbm=isch"

# fetch link for download
imagelink=$(wget -e robots=off --user-agent "$useragent" -qO - "$link" | sed 's/</\n</g' | grep '<a href.*\(png\|jpg\|jpeg\)' | sed 's/.*imgurl=\([^&]*\)\&.*/\1/' | head -n $count | tail -n1)
imagelink="${imagelink%\%*}"

# get file extention (.png, .jpg, .jpeg)
ext=$(echo $imagelink | sed "s/.*\(\.[^\.]*\)$/\1/")

# set default save location and file name change this!!
dir="$PWD"
file="google image"

# get optional second argument, which defines the file name or dir
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
    if [ -d "$2" ]; then
        dir="$2"
    else
        file="${2}"
        mkdirs "${dir}"
        dir=""
    fi
fi   

# construct image link: add 'echo "${google_image}"'
# after this line for debug output
google_image="${dir}/${file}"

# construct name, append number if file exists
if [[ -e "${google_image}${ext}" ]] ; then
    i=0
    while [[ -e "${google_image}(${i})${ext}" ]] ; do
        ((i++))
    done
    google_image="${google_image}(${i})${ext}"
else
    google_image="${google_image}${ext}"
fi

# get actual picture and store in google_image.$ext
wget --max-redirect 0 -qO "${google_image}" "${imagelink}"

# if 'o' flag supplied: open image
[[ $option = "o" ]] && gnome-open "${google_image}"

# successful execution, exit code 0
exit 0
```

The comments should be self explanatory, if you have any questions about the code (such as the long pipeline) I'll be happy to clarify the mechanics. Note that I had to set a more detailed user agent on the wget, it may happen that you need to set a different user agent but I don't think it'll be a problem. If you do have a problem, visit  [http://whatsmyuseragent.com/](http://whatsmyuseragent.com) and supply the output in the `useragent` variable.

When you wish to open the image instead of only downloading, use the `-o` flag, example below. If you wish to extend the script and also include a custom output file name, just let me know and I'll add it for you.

Example usage:

```
$ chmod +x getimg.sh
$ ./getimg.sh 1 dog
$ gnome-open google_image.jpg
$ ./getimg.sh -o 10 donkey
```

Comment: @tom My pleasure, check out the script too!

Comment: Hmm but unfortunately the image is not in full resolution, it is only in the resolution it is shown on google search page.

Comment: I'm afraid google doesn't supply a link to the original image in their website code. It must be javascript that handle's linking to the original image. If you can find it in google's code (using a browser's "inspect element") I'll be happy to take care of it.

Comment: It is there. Google 'dog' and than you can find for example http://animalia-life.com/data_images/dog/dog4.jpg in google's code view-source:https://www.google.cz/search?q=dog

Comment: I was mistaken, I will look into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68681/discussion-between-shellfish-and-tom).

Comment: @ShellFish Can you modify this to download multiple images? I tried this `bash getimg.sh 1 mounteverest&&bash getimg.sh 5 mounteverest` It retrieved both images, but only saved one to the working folder. I deally I'd like the script to download 30 images and automatically save them to the working folder.

Comment: The script should now take a second argument, which is either a target dir (where it will save the image as "google image.ext" or "google image(1).ext" etc if the file already exists. You can also supply a  file name as second argument such as `/home/user/Documents/images/image`. The extension will be added automatically. -- Let me kniw if there are bugs.

Comment: @ShellFish I get the following error when I run your updated script: `getimages.sh: line 44: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
getimages.sh: line 44: syntax error near `${google_image}($'
getimages.sh: line 44: `    while [[ -e ${google_image}(${i}).${ext} ]] ; do'`

Comment: @User8547 Should be fixed now, report further bugs please.

Comment: @ShellFish When I run `bash getimg.sh 2 applepie` I get the error `Error showing url: Error when getting information for file '/home/poppy/Scripts/google_image.jpg': No such file or directory`. But it still downloads the pic, sans the extension.

Comment: @ShellFish When I run `bash getimg.sh 6 applepie /home/poppy/Desktop/images/image` I get the error `getimg.sh: line 11: [: applepie: binary operator expected
/home/Cedar/Desktop/images/image: No such file or directory
Error showing url: Error when getting information for file '/home/poppy/Scripts/google_image': No such file or directory`. It doesn't download a pic or create a folder.

Comment: @ShellFish What command should I use to download multiple pics? It's unclear to me.

Comment: Use  a `for` loop to download multiple pics, I think it will work now. Once a single page works fine, you should post another question for further optimizations. Try to post them in a general way and then try to apply it to this script. Post another question if you have problems doing so.

Comment: @ShellFish Did you see the error messages I posted above? I have beginners knowledge so some of this is above my head.

Comment: I will have to look at it later, maybe in couple weeks when my exams are over because I'm spending some serious time debugging. I'm sorry. But I will make it work, hope you can wait a little while longer!

Comment: No wait I think I found it, give it one more try please.

Comment: @ShellFish Your latest worked. I used the following amatuerish command to download 10 images: `bash getimg.sh 1 applepie&&bash getimg.sh 2 applepie&&bash getimg.sh 3 applepie&&bash getimg.sh 4 applepie&&bash getimg.sh 5 applepie&&bash getimg.sh 6 applepie&&bash getimg.sh 7 applepie&&bash getimg.sh 8 applepie&&bash getimg.sh 9 applepie&&bash getimg.sh 10 applepie` I haven't learned how to use the `for loop` yet. It opened each image after download, which I don't want. I didn't use the `o` option, so I don't know why the images opened. Also, it downloaded 1 junk image which was 0 bytes.

Comment: @ShellFish It would be nice if you could modify the script to allow me to use phrases, e.g. "apple pie" instead of "applepie". Also I don't know if it works only on Safe Search, but it would be nice if it worked by default with Safe Search off so as to retrieve any images. It would also be neat to incorporate the script with YAD, so that users could input search terms into a dialog box, and choose the download folder and some other options. But that's putting the cart before the horse right now.

Comment: I think you need to do `apple%20pie`, that's how google handles spaces. I will add some comments for you to construct a for loop and fix the open bug.

Comment: Tell you what, why don't you google `bash for loop` give it a shot, if you fail simply create a SO question where you say: "I have a script which I need to execute x times, I tried using a for loop but it's not working, I get this error: ...". You can ask anything you want as long as you include an attempt (important to post your code, any attempt shows you tried). Somebody will definitely answer.

Comment: @ShellFish Tx! I upvoted your original answer and comments. The `%20` method works great.

Comment: Thanks no need to upvote everything though, just the stuff you deemed quality posts! Good luck trying the for loop!

Comment: just a note for future reader: sed on OS X (yosemite) won't create the new line with \n I had to use:  sed -e 's/</\'$'\n</g' and then later on:  tr " " "\n"

Answer (score 9):

This is an addition to the answer provided by [ShellFish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1775715/shellfish). Much respect to them for working this out. **:)**

Google have recently changed their web-code for the image results page which has, unfortunately, broken Shellfish's code. I was using it every night in a cron job up until about 4 days ago when it stopped receiving search-results. While investigating this, I found that Google have removed elements like imgurl and have shifted a lot more into javascript.

My solution is an expansion of Shellfish's great code but has modifications to handle these Google changes and includes some 'enhancements' of my own.

It performs a single Google search, saves the results, bulk-downloads a specified number of images, then builds these into a single gallery-image using ImageMagick. Up to 1,000 images can be requested.

This bash script is available at https://git.io/googliser

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for updating this, I will merge your answer into mine later if that's okay with you. Of course you'll get the credit you deserve!

Comment: I just checked the script, you it's really nice. You should consider moving it to a public github repo though. People can then fork it and perform pull requests for possible extensions. Maybe it can even end up on public repos such as Arch's AUR! Thanks for the credit btw!

Comment: Thanks ShellFish. :) Good call on GitHub. I created an account yesterday and have now uploaded the script to a public repo. I've updated the link to point to GitHub. Now - just need to learn how to use it! lol...

Comment: I have adapted your code to work on Mac OSX: it mostly requires installing some GNU utilities and swapping them for the native ones in the googliser. You can find the script [here](https://gist.github.com/dardo82/567eac882b678badfd097bae501b64e2).

Comment: Thanks! It lets me find portraits using OpenCV and NodeJS in [the script](http://gist.github.com/dardo82/dcb643db39f0757a512db1f555df59c5) here.

Answer (score 1):

Python code to download high resolution images from Google. i had poste the original  answer here [Python - Download Images from google Image search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716842/python-download-images-from-google-image-search/28487500#28487500)

Currently downloads 100  original images given a search query

**Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import urllib2
import os
import cookielib
import json

def get_soup(url,header):
    return BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url,headers=header)))


query = raw_input("query image")# you can change the query for the image  here
image_type="ActiOn"
query= query.split()
query='+'.join(query)
url="https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+query+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
print url
#add the directory for your image here
DIR="C:\\Users\\Rishabh\\Pictures\\"+query.split('+')[0]+"\\"
header={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"
}
soup = get_soup(url,header)


ActualImages=[]# contains the link for Large original images, type of  image
for a in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"rg_meta"}):
    link , Type =json.loads(a.text)["ou"]  ,json.loads(a.text)["ity"]
    ActualImages.append((link,Type))

print  "there are total" , len(ActualImages),"images"


###print images
for i , (img , Type) in enumerate( ActualImages):
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(img, headers={'User-Agent' : header})
        raw_img = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
        if not os.path.exists(DIR):
            os.mkdir(DIR)
        cntr = len([i for i in os.listdir(DIR) if image_type in i]) + 1
        print cntr
        if len(Type)==0:
            f = open(DIR + image_type + "_"+ str(cntr)+".jpg", 'wb')
        else :
            f = open(DIR + image_type + "_"+ str(cntr)+"."+Type, 'wb')


        f.write(raw_img)
        f.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print "could not load : "+img
        print e
```

Answer (score 0):

as for shelfish's answer

```
imagelink=$(wget -e robots=off --user-agent "$useragent" -qO - "$link" | sed 's/\"ou\"/\n\"ou\"/g' | grep '\"ou\"\:\".*\(png\|jpg\|jpeg\).*ow\"' | awk -F'"' '{print $4}' | head -n $count|tail -n1)
```

will work with the current google image search june 2016

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, for files < 4 MB only (otherwise you get a TLS error):

```
wget --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0" -qO - "$@" |grep video.googleusercontent.com|cut -d'"' -f2|wget --content-disposition -c -i -
```