# Python Google Images download does not work

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm crawling an image through Google Image downloader.
The code that originally worked started to suddenly stop working
How do we solve this problem? Code and error messages are as follows

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download   

def ImageCrawling(keyword, dir):
    response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()  

    arguments = {"keywords":keyword 
        ,"limit":2 
        ,"print_urls":True 
        ,'output_directory':dir}   
    paths = response.download(arguments)   #passing the arguments to the function
    print(paths)   #printing absolute paths of the downloaded images

ImageCrawling('dog','C:\\nuguya')
```

[image]

Comment: There are several other ways to dowload google images in python, given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716842/python-download-images-from-google-image-search

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I tried to proceed with the information I posted, but it's not working. I'm not crawling because of image copyright on Google or I don't know if that's the problem

Comment: @변구훈 did you find any solution? I was drawling the urls for images using that API (not downloading) then suddenly it stopped working as well :(

Comment: @Skynet094 
The confirmation is late. I eventually decided to crawl a non-Google website image

Comment: Would you please share the code do to it if it's okay? Thanks!  It's fine if it is not

Answer (score 1):

It seems google recently removed the `rg_metadata` from the page, which is what `google_images_download` was using to process the images from the raw_html.
As such it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the py file from the Ubuntu terminal. It works fine. I think it's not working in Windows OS.