# for a in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"rg_meta"}): NOT working

Tags: python

I hope this question will find you in the best of health and spirit. I use this python script for image scrapping but this loop is not working. Can any one suggest me solution this is script?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import urllib.request as urllib2
import os
import argparse
import sys
import json

# adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716842/python-download-images-from-google-image-search

def get_soup(url,header):
    return BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url,headers=header)),'html.parser')

def main(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Scrape Google images')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--search', default='bananas', type=str, help='search term')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--num_images', default=10, type=int, help='num images to save')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', default='/Users/gene/Downloads/', type=str, help='save directory')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    query = args.search#raw_input(args.search)
    max_images = args.num_images
    save_directory = args.directory
    image_type="Action"
    query=input()
    query= query.split()
    query='+'.join(query)
    url="https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+query+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
    header={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"}
    soup = get_soup(url,header)
    ActualImages=[]# contains the link for Large original images, type of  image
    for a in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"rg_meta"}):
        link , Type =json.loads(a.text)["ou"]  ,json.loads(a.text)["ity"]
        ActualImages.append((link,Type))
    for i , (img , Type) in enumerate( ActualImages[0:max_images]):
        try:
            req = urllib2.Request(img, headers={'User-Agent' : header})
            raw_img = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
            if len(Type)==0:
                f = open(os.path.join(save_directory , "img" + "_"+ str(i)+".jpg"), 'wb')
            else :
                f = open(os.path.join(save_directory , "img" + "_"+ str(i)+"."+Type), 'wb')
            f.write(raw_img)
            f.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print ("could not load : "+img)
            print (e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv
    try:
        main(argv)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

To scrape Google Images data, especially images in original resolution, you need to get them from [inline JSON](https://dev.to/serpapi/13-ways-to-scrape-any-public-data-from-any-website-1bn9#inline-json) using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Otherwise, you can extract it with browser automation such as `selenium`, however, scraping speed would be a lot slower in comparison to regex.

To find if there's an inline json present or not, you can start by looking for the title of the first image in the page source (`Ctrl+U`) to find the matches we need, and if they are in the `<script>` elements, then most likely this is inline JSON. From there we can extract the data.

We can find both thumbnails and full resolution images. First, using `regular expressions` we find thumbnails, and then with the original resolution:

```py
# https://regex101.com/r/SxwJsW/1
matched_google_images_thumbnails = ", ".join(
    re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                       str(matched_google_image_data))).split(", ")
    
thumbnails = [bytes(bytes(thumbnail, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails]
    
# removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', "", str(matched_google_image_data))
    
# https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]", removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)
```

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-image#main.py).

```py
import requests, re, json, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

google_images = []

params = {    
    "q": "tower",              # search query
    "tbm": "isch",             # image results
    "hl": "en",                # language of the search
    "gl": "us"                # country where search comes fro
}
    
html = requests.get("https://google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    
all_script_tags = soup.select("script")
    
# https://regex101.com/r/RPIbXK/1
matched_images_data = "".join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)
      
# https://regex101.com/r/NRKEmV/1
matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\"b-GRID_STATE0\"(.*)sideChannel:\s?{}}', matched_images_data_json)
    
# https://regex101.com/r/SxwJsW/1
matched_google_images_thumbnails = ", ".join(
    re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                       str(matched_google_image_data))).split(", ")
    
thumbnails = [bytes(bytes(thumbnail, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails]
    
# removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', "", str(matched_google_image_data))
    
# https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]", removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)
    
full_res_images = [
        bytes(bytes(img, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for img in matched_google_full_resolution_images
]
        
for index, (metadata, thumbnail, original) in enumerate(zip(soup.select('.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd'), thumbnails, full_res_images), start=1):
    google_images.append({
        "title": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["title"],
        "link": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["href"],
        "source": metadata.select_one(".fxgdke").text,
        "thumbnail": thumbnail,
        "original": original
    })

print(json.dumps(google_images, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Eiffel Tower - Wikipedia",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_Tower",
    "source": "Wikipedia",
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsuYzf9os1Qb1ssPO6fWn-5Jm6ASDXAxUFYG6eJfvmehywH-tJEXDW0t7XLR3-i8cNd-0&usqp=CAU",
    "original": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons_%28cropped%29.jpg/640px-Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons_%28cropped%29.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "tower | architecture | Britannica",
    "link": "https://www.britannica.com/technology/tower",
    "source": "Encyclopedia Britannica",
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8EsWofNiFTe6alwRlwXVR64RdWTG2fuBQ0z1FX4tg3HbL7Mxxvz6GnG1rGZQA8glVNA4&usqp=CAU",
    "original": "https://cdn.britannica.com/51/94351-050-86B70FE1/Leaning-Tower-of-Pisa-Italy.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "Tower - Wikipedia",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower",
    "source": "Wikipedia",
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT3L9LA0VamqmevhCtkrHZvM9MlBf9EjtTT7KhyzRP3zi3BmuCOmn0QFQG42xFfWljcsho&usqp=CAU",
    "original": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Tokyo_Sky_Tree_2012.JPG"
  },
  # ...
]
```

---

As an alternative you can use [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Simple code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os, json

image_results = []
   
# search query parameters
params = {
    "engine": "google",               # search engine. Google, Bing, Yahoo, Naver, Baidu...
    "q": "tower",                     # search query
    "tbm": "isch",                    # image results
    "num": "100",                     # number of images per page
    "ijn": 0,                         # page number: 0 -> first page, 1 -> second...
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY")   # your serpapi api key
                                      # other query parameters: hl (lang), gl (country), etc  
}
    
search = GoogleSearch(params)         # where data extraction happens
    
images_is_present = True
while images_is_present:
    results = search.get_dict()       # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
# checks for "Google hasn't returned any results for this query."
    if "error" not in results:
        for image in results["images_results"]:
            if image["original"] not in image_results:
                    image_results.append(image["original"])
                
# update to the next page
        params["ijn"] += 1
    else:
        print(results["error"])
        images_is_present = False

print(json.dumps(image_results, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
[
  "https://cdn.rt.emap.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2022/08/10084135/shutterstock-woods-bagot-rough-site-for-leadenhall-tower.jpg",
  "https://dynamic-media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/1c/60/ff/c5/ambuluwawa-tower-is-the.jpg?w=1200&h=-1&s=1",
  "https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-bf3bb/product_images/uploaded_images/find-your-nearest-cell-tower-in-five-minutes-or-less.jpeg",
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/reuniontower/Reunion-Tower-Exterior-Skyline.jpg",
  "https://assets2.rockpapershotgun.com/minecraft-avengers-tower.jpg/BROK/resize/1920x1920%3E/format/jpg/quality/80/minecraft-avengers-tower.jpg",
  "https://images.adsttc.com/media/images/52ab/5834/e8e4/4e0f/3700/002e/large_jpg/PERTAMINA_1_Tower_from_Roundabout.jpg?1386960835",
  "https://awoiaf.westeros.org/images/7/78/The_tower_of_joy_by_henning.jpg",
  "https://eu-assets.simpleview-europe.com/plymouth2016/imageresizer/?image=%2Fdmsimgs%2Fsmeatontower3_606363908.PNG&action=ProductDetailNew",
  # ...
]
```

There's a [Scrape and download Google Images with Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-images-with-python/) blog post if you need a little bit more code explanation.